# Want to show that asymptotic expansion of $T[\phi](x)=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\alpha |x-y|)\phi(y)dx$ converges in the operator norm?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

Let $T:L^2([0,2\pi]) \to H^1([0,2\pi])$ be an integral operator given by

$$
T[\phi](x) = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\alpha |x-y|) \phi(y) dy.
$$
I want to show that this operator can be asymptotically expanded with respect to $\alpha$ and that the expansion converges in the operator norm of $\mathcal{L}(L^2([0,2\pi]),H^1([0,2\pi]))$.

Regarding the asymptotic expansion, that is straightforward because I can just Taylor expand the kernel $k(x,y) = \sin(\alpha |x-y|)$ as

$$
\begin{align}
k(x,y) & = \alpha|x-y| - \frac{1}{6}\alpha^3|x-y|^3 + \frac{1}{120}\alpha^5|x-y|^5 + \dots
\end{align}.
$$
So then I define
$$
T_j[\phi](x) = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{j!}\frac{d^j}{d\alpha^j}\sin(\alpha|x-y|)\bigg|_{\alpha = 0}\phi(y)dy.
$$

Now I can write
$$
T[\phi](x) = \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \alpha^j T_j\right)[\phi](x)
$$
So how do I then show that the series $\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \alpha^j T_j\right)$ converges in the operator norm of $\mathcal{L}(L^2([0,2\pi]),H^1([0,2\pi]))$?